# Short-term luggage storage in Alpe d'Huez

Tags: luggage, france, luggage-storage

We have to check out at 10:00h from our apartment in Alpe d'Huez and then our bus departs only after 15:00h. The agency doesn't have any luggage storage facilities. Where can we leave our luggage for the day?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately it seems there are no luggage storage facilities in Alpe d'Huez, so double check with the accommodation provider if they have such facilities before you book.